# How to Match Bracket Pairs skipping Escape Ones using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I am using Javascipt/Typescript to extract substrings wrapped by curly brackets "{}". It is guaranteed that there are no nested brackets, but there could be some brackets with escape notation "\{" or "\}". For these escaped brackets, they are just normal strings.

Eg.:

valid:

```
{abc} ==> abc
{a\{bc} ==> a\{bc
{ab}{c} ==> ab, c
```

invalid:

```
{a{bc}d}
```

I tried to use something like this: `{[^{}]*}` to match, and I noticed that `lookingbehind` might help, but I am not sure how to properly use it in Javascript/typescript, especially in negated set. Could anyone shoot me an example of this?

Answer (score 2):

Using negative lookbehind assertion you may use this regex:

```sh
(?<!{[^{]*){(?:\\.|[^}{])*}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HdVhVg/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!{[^{]*)`: Assert that we don't have a `{` followed by 0 or more non-`{` character before current position
- `{`: Match opening `{`
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `\\.`: Match any escaped character
  - `|`: OR
  - `[^}{]`: Match 0 or more of any character that are not `{` and `}`
- `)*`: End non-capture group. Repeat this group 0 or more times
- `}`: Match closing `}`

Answer (score 1):

For the escape character, we should take care that the initial brace is not escaped. In fact, a backslash could itself be escaped, and so we could have a (longer) sequence of backslashes...

I would suggest this:

```js
let regex = /(?<!\\)(?:\\.)*{((?:\\.|[^{}])*)}/g

// Using String.raw so all backslashes are literal:
let input = String.raw`
{abc}
{d\{ef}
{gh}{i}
\\\{j{k\\}
`;

// Output all matches (capture group 1)
for (let [all, grp] of input.matchAll(regex)) {
    console.log(grp);
}
```

#### The parts of the regex

- `(?<!\\)`: matching should not start right after a backslash
- `(?:\\.)*`: a sequence of escaped characters (`\` followed by a second character).
- `{`: a literal opening brace
- `((?:\\.|[^{}])*)`: the capture group of interest: a sequence of escaped characters or non-brace characters.
- `}`: a literal closing brace.

The regex will match more than just the part between braces: the braces are included and any preceding backslashes also. The single capture group will have the part the occurs inside the braces.